# Method called after latest render

Tags: reactjs, state, render, lifecycle

In my reactjs application, in one component, render function is called many times. I have some data available only at the last time the render is called. I need to do some treatments on this data. Where can I do it?

```
componentWillMount() {
    get(this.props, 'myarraydata', []).forEach(element => {
        //here i will do some treatments for each elemment
    });
}

render() {
    console.log(get(this.props, 'myarraydata', []));

    return (
        <div>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(get(this.props, 'myarraydata', []), null, 2) }</pre>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see, in my application, this render method is called many times, and it uses myarraydata passed from another component and myarraydata is available only when render is called for the last time (means when render is called for the first, second, .. times, my arraydata is empty). but the problem is that componentwillmount method is called only one time, and at that time, myarraydata still empty and i can't do the treatments i need

Comment: Can you please post some code? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method.

Need elaboration on

> I have some data available only at the last time the render is called

What does this mean exactly?

EDIT : Try this :

```
componentWillMount() {
  let data = get(this.props, 'myarraydata', [])
  if(data.length !== 0){
   data.forEach(element => {
    //here i will do some treatments for each elemment
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: please see my post updated, let me know if you need more details

Comment: thank you @Shivam Gupta, I think the above answer of estus will work

Comment: Oh great. Don't forget to up vote his answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

[`componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is called after each subsequent render, as it can be seen on [this diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/):

[image: lifecycle diagram]

otice that it isn't called on initial render when `componentDidMount` is called instead after `render` hook.

Data that was received via props can be processed there, this requires to call `setState` or `forceUpdate` then to make it rendered.

In original code, this requires to introduce the state to this component. Also, [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) was deprecated because it was commonly misused for cases like this one. It should be replaced with constructor code or `componentDidMount`. In this case the state synchronously derives from `myarraydata` prop, this is what [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) is for:

```
state = { processedData: null };

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (conditionsToNotProcessData) return null;

  const processedData = props.myarraydata || [];
  for (const item of processedData) { ... }

  return { ...state, processedData };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.processedData)}</pre>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I need to do my treatments only one time when render function is called with non empty data. So i can't use componentdidmount because it is called just after the first render and at that time data is empty.
I can't use componentdidupdate because it is called everytime render is called so many times, and i need to run my treatments only one time

Comment: I updated the answer with how I'd expect this to be done. You likely have to control when data is processed and when it's not.

Comment: thank you @estus
it will help me. if i'm not mistaken, getDerivedStateFromProps will be called always before render. Is it possible to say "call this method always before render but as soon as myarraydata is not empty, we stop calling it" ?

Comment: There's no need to really stop calling it. This is what `conditionsToNotProcessData` is for. The indicator for that data was processed once is that `processedData` is not empty, correct? Then it will be `if (state.processedData) return null`.

Comment: and how can i set the conditionsToNotProcessData, if a store it in component state, i will need to call set state inside getDerivedStateFromProps method and this may lead to endless loop

Comment: You don't need to call setState in getDerivedStateFromProps (and fortunately, there's no way to do that because it's static and doesn't have access to `this.setState`). It's supposed to synchronously return modified state, as shown in the answer.

Comment: ooooh yeaaah, good solution it seems. Thanks @estus, I will try it, hope it helps me

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm using react 16.2  and getDerivedStateFromProps was introduced in React 16.3 version, so can't use it